# How to initialize an array to empty?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, hashtable

My current class project is dealing with hashtables. We are able to use whatever language we want, however the professor uses c++.

This is the sample code he provided us that we are supposed to copy over:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      this->theTable[i] = EMPTY;
```

He says this will set the array, theTable, to empty.

How am I supposed to do this in Java? Isn't an array in Java always set to 0 if its empty? Is this code equivalent?

```
 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           this.theTable[i] = 0;
 }
```

Comment: What type is `theTable`?

Comment: That code is not necessary in Java, as you noted every Java array has a default initial value for its' elements. `int[] theTable = new int[size];` is equivalent. Assuming `theTable` is an array of `int`.

Comment: Yes, theTable is an int array, sorry. So no point to have the for loop then correct?

Comment: In addition to what @ElliottFrisch said, this code is correct (and needed) if `theTable` is of type `Integer[]`

Comment: What is `EMPTY`?

Comment: you can always print and see the values of an array yourself `Arrays.stream(theTable).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Im not sure what EMPTY is. No idea if its a c++ thing or not. But nothing else about it in the sample code given to us.